# Что исправить(дополнить) чтобы зароботало в ИЕ 8

Tags: javascript

```
<script language="" type="text/javascript">
function toggle( el ) {
   el.style.display = (el.style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
   var hide_arr = document.querySelectorAll( 'div[id^="spoiler_"]:not([id="' + el.id + '"])' );
   Array.prototype.forEach.call( hide_arr, function( hide, i ) {
    hide.style.display = 'none';
   });
}
</script>

<div onclick="toggle(document.getElementById('spoiler_content'))">Кликни на меня</div>
<div onclick="toggle(document.getElementById('spoiler_content1'))">Кликни на меня</div>
<br>
<div id="spoiler_content" style="display:none">Какой-то текст....<br /> И еще текст</div><div id="spoiler_content1" style="display:none">Какой-то текст....<br /> 
И еще текст</div>
```

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что не работает в IE? в какой версии IE? какие ошибки в консоли?

Comment: в ИЕ8 не работает при нажатии на следующую ссылку открытая не закрывается Сведения об ошибке на веб-странице



Сообщение: Объект не поддерживает это свойство или метод
Строка: 6
Символ: 2
Код: 0

Comment: Добавь в вопрос, что речь идет именно об IE8

Answer (score 1):

В приведенном коде используется несколько возможностей недоступных в IE8

1. [*Array.prototype.forEach*](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) - вместо него придется использовать обычный цикл
2. [*document.querySelectorAll*](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) может принимать только селекторы CSS2, в то время, как [*:not*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) это селектор CSS3

В итоге код можно переписать так:

```
function toggle( el ) {
    el.style.display = (el.style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
    var els = document.querySelectorAll( 'div[id^="spoiler_"]' )
    for(var i=0, len=els.length; i<len; i++){
        var hide = els[i];
        if(el.id != hide.id){
            hide.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо ВСЕМ решение найдено

```
<script language="" type="text/javascript">

function toggle(hide_id)
{
   var el = document.getElementById(hide_id);
   if ( el.style.display != "none" )
   {
       el.style.display = 'none';
   }
   else
   {
       el.style.display = '';
   }
}
function hideElements(hide_id)
{
var hides = ['hide', 'hide1', 'hide2', 'hide3'];
for(var i = 0; i < hides.length; i++)
{
    if(hide_id !== hides[i])
{
document.getElementById(hides[i]).style.display='none';
}
}
toggle(hide_id);
}

</script>
```